# what happens to window events when changing documents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, browser-history

Hey i have the following `statechange` event set on the window :

```
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(e){ 
 console.log("statechange event occured ");
 //more code
    var newDoc = document.open();
    newDoc.write(file);
    newDoc.close();
});
```

i'm using history.js but that doesn't matter in this case as it binds the statechange regulary, i am getting the value of `file` like should be and works fine.

Now i have this code (and other code) inside an external js file, 
inside the file i'm iterating through all `a` tags and apply the following click event :

```
    $(element).on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //more code

    History.pushState({file : file},title, fullHref);


});
```

Now when i click the document is getting changed as expected but when trying to use back/forward buttons `statechange` event does not fire.

**I should mention that this js is included in the files im loading as well.**

So my initial thought was that as the document changes but the window doesn't, the event remains. which is not true as it applies the statechange event multipile times. So i tried applying the event once using cookie but that still does the same thing.

Now if instead of changing the document i simply apply it with jQuerys `.html()` the statechange event gets fired as exepected so i guess it's related to the document.

Why could this happen? I believe if i understood more about what happens to window events when changing documents i could solve this problem.

**Tries :**

- I have now also tried binding to the `popstate` event via regular History API, still same results give or take. `pushState` doesn't fire popstate but back button does but without state.
- I have come to the conclusion that i shouldn't be using history.js as i susspect the problem came from there so i "solved" my problems with popstate which still causing problems as document.open seems to be firing popstate. still looking for more information
- I've tried using `on`, same result

**Information** :

- the fact this example us using **History** is because of history.js, if i use regular history API still same problems.

I have read in mdn that :

> > {{ gecko_minversion_note("1.9.2", "Starting with Gecko 1.9.2, document.open() uses the
>
> principal of the document whose URI it uses, instead of fetching the
>   principal off the stack. As a result, you can no longer call
>   document.write() into an untrusted document from chrome, even using
>   wrappedJSObject.") }}

Which im not sure but i think could be realted to this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in the end i discovered that all though you only change document, window events gets deleted as they lay inside the document.

I encoutred my problems with History.js i think because the fact that im changing documents break it at some point.

What i did was use native HTML5 history API and rebinded the `popstate` event in the new document.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to bind the element with LIVE ?

```
$(element).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //more code
    History.pushState({file : file},title, fullHref);
});
```

becomes

```
$(element).live('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //more code
        History.pushState({file : file},title, fullHref);
    });
```

Comment: live is not used anymore, you should use `on` now and yeah i did didn't help. using `click` is just one of my tries.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `iframe` to load your document and easily can change its document. Then, you can listen for a click event like this,

```
$("#iframe").load(function () {
    $(this.contentWindow).click(function () {
        // do your click events here
    });
});
```

The iframe will reload if you change the `src` attribute value as another document.

Comment: i don't `have` to use iframe and i can't use an iframe. my clicks event does happen when i use `document.open()`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a target in the document.open() method (see 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_open.asp)?
If not' you're actually writing to a blank window, where you might be losing the History object.

Comment: the information in w3schools is not reliable, other websites like mdn doesn't mention those attribues.

Comment: Have you tried tracing the History object on clicking, so you can see if the object is the same object as the root level History object?

Comment: No i havn't but it's irrelavent as i solved it in the end, thank you for trying to help!

Comment: I'm thinking the History objects get discarded upon overwriting the document, since it is probably attached to the DOM, the native history API is probably bound higher up though...
Good to see you found a fix for it.